# running brew commands is full of 'Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.'

Tags: macos, homebrew

This affects many other things too but in brew you may see lots of things suggesting:
'Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.'

Brew explicitly recommends you do not run it under sudo.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

running brew doctor gave me useful answers to this

Provided software update is closed you may be able to agree to the license by opening Xcode.app, but I couldn't... so instead I ran:

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

Which if you scroll to the bottom lets you type 'agree' and then you're good to go.